# base R — how to detect if var-args (...) had key names (named parameters) assigned?

Tags: r, variadic-functions

**I’d like to detect if the given var-args (...) to some function `blah(...)` has keys (named parameters) assigned by the caller:**

```
blah = function(...) {
   # detect if key-names were given to ‘...’
   args = list(...)  #  seems to always have:  length(names(args)) == 2
}

# example calls:
blah(key1=someList1, userAssignedKeyName=someList2)
blah(someList1,someList2)
```

1. `length(names(list(...))) == 0` doesn’t seem possible—R seems to default to some internal toString() representation for the name of key; ie, `length(names(...)) == 2` **always**.
2. I can’t declare function **`blah(...)`** as **`blah(key1=“”, key2=“”)`** and then `detect by equality with “”` because:

   i.  This loses the var-args property

•  **In base-R, how do I detect if the user has passed key-names (named their parameters) to `...` above?**

(It doesn’t seem possible to me since the R language spec seems to assume no ordering guarantees on named parameters; and also that the naming of parameters is done by the coder, not the caller; and that no such syntax for ... is supported).

Thanks!

**EDIT:  I think a kwargs named-list like Python is the way to go? So I’d drop the ‘...’ and use a named-list like a kwargs in Python.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean here. If you want to know whether the user called the function using parameter names you can do:

```r
blah <- function(...) names(list(...))
```

So, in your set-up we might have:

```r
someList1 <- list(a = "foo")
someList2 <- list(a = "bar")

blah(key1 = someList1, userAssignedKeyName = someList2)
#> [1] "key1"                "userAssignedKeyName"

blah(someList1, someList2) 
#> NULL
```

And contrary to what your question implies, if we have:

```r
blah <- function(...) length(names(list(...)))
```

Then we get:

```
blah(key1 = someList1, userAssignedKeyName = someList2)
#> [1] 2

blah(someList1, someList2) 
#> [1] 0
```

Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Thank you for kind and very helpful reply. I think you are most likely right — I must have some other bugs in my code -.- (I am new to R).  I will check immediately and let you know what I see.  If it is my own bug then I will accept it asap. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it seems it was some weird bug I had in the process of writing the code. The actual code is more complicated with purrr maps and accumulate’s and stuff (^.^”””)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly. Is this what you want?

```
blah <- function(...) {
    sum(names(list(...)) != "")
}

blah()
# [1] 0
blah(a = 2, b = 3)
# [1] 2
blah(2, a = 3)
# [1] 1
```

This function only counts named parameters, since:

> The name "" is special: it is used to indicate that there is no name associated with an element of a (atomic or generic) vector. (see `?names`)

Comment: Yes, this is actually a perfect example. The other guy posted before you, but this is also a perfectly great and helpful answer. Thank you.  Note that, just now I did length(name(list(...))) without a vector equality to “”, which was *another* bug currently where I can only detect 0 or length(list(...)) — nothing in-between as “1” in your example. Your test to “” indeed captures that. You know your stuff! thanks.